# In 'The Sign of the Four', what happened to the Sikh accomplices at the end?

Tags: arthur-conan-doyle, sherlock-holmes, plot-element

Jonathan Small always maintained how he was loyal throughout to his other three Sikh/Indian accomplices. The last we read of them was when they all met with Sholto and Mortsan and told them about the treasure. But later on when Jonathan Small managed to escape with Tonga, he didn't mention anything about what happened to his other three accomplices. All I can speculate is:

1. Either they die, which Jonathan fails to mention or imply
2. They were moved to other places, but Jonathan forgot about them (?), didn't even look for them to help with his quest to find Sholto and hence the treasure. This is contrary to his claim of loyalty.
3. He left them there on the Andaman Islands, which is contrary to his claim of loyalty.